# Associate array of different types in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# (coming from a web dev background, using JS and PHP) and I want to know if it's possible to create an associative array of different types in C#.

For example, in PHP I can do something like:

```
$arr = [
   ['name' => 'Jack', 'age' => 24, 'averageGrade' => 7.23],
   ['name' => 'Jessica', 'age' => 29, 'averageGrade' => 8.12],
   ['name' => 'Joe', 'age' => 22, 'averageGrade' => 9.51]
];
```

Is there a way to do this in C#? And is there a way to create them so that they can take as much data as I want? For example, maybe then I want to add a field for each one called `favouriteColor`.

And then, how do I loop through it? In PHP is super easy doing:

```
foreach($item as $arr => $value){
    echo $value['name']; //jack, jessica, joe
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this in C#: 
I don't claim this the best way, but it gives an idea.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ShowNames
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var People = new Collection<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { Name = "Jack", Age = 24, AverageGrade = 7.23 },
                new Person() { Name = "Jessica",  Age = 29,   AverageGrade = 8.12 },
                new Person() { Name = "Joe", Age = 25, AverageGrade = 9.51 },
            };

            foreach (var PersonItem in People)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", PersonItem.Name);
            }

        }

    }

    internal class Person
    {
        public string Name;
        public decimal Age;
        public double AverageGrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Anonymous Types

```
var anonArray = new[] {
    new { name = "Jack", age = 24, averageGrade = 7.23 },
    new { name = "Jessica", age = 29, averageGrade = 8.12 },
    new { name = "Joe", age = 22, averageGrade = 9.51 }
};
```

But I call this "the lazy way". I would strongly recommend defining a class even for a small structure.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things that can be said here.

First of all, [you might want to look into the dynamic type in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic), which avoids compile time type checking, and instead a type is defined at run-time. However, you cannot add properties dynamically; in this sense, I think you'll want to check out [ExpandoObject, which, quoting the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8), "represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time".

However, and I think this has to be said, specially since you come from JS, which is not a statically typed language as Java or c# are (instead, it is a dynamic typed language): you'll want to be careful when using this things and be mindful of the good coding practices. After all, c# is a statically typed language, so bypassing the compile time type checking is simply unreasonable in most cases; it doesn't quite make sense. In other words, it probably means you're not using OOP properly. For instance, your classes might simply not be well designed, or there might be a better solution that takes advantage of types that you're simply not seeing.

Good luck! Hope this helped.

Comment: First of all, a `Dictionary<string, object>` would make more sense than a `List<dynamic>` here, and then, it should be noted that Reflection has a performance cost at run-time

Comment: If it sounded like I was actually recommending using a `List<dynamic>` then I expressed myself wrong. I just meant that, regarding bypassing compile-time type checking she/he might find useful checking the dynamic type. Also, I further added that to add 'properties' at run-time, checking out ExpandoObject might also make sense. I just meant that instead of having a dictionary of people paired with *something*, he might simply want an array of *somethings* with the ability to dynamically add properties. Note that I also advised against it (or to at least do it with caution).